# Show absolute and uniform convergence of a Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Hello and good evening!

The Fourier series of $f(x):=\lvert x\rvert$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is
$$
f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2}.
$$

I have to examine if this Series is absolutely convergent and uniformly convergent.

1) absolute convergence

I know *absolute convergence* as the follows: A series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i$ is called absolutely convergent if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lvert c_i\rvert<\infty$.

Now I want to apply this on my Fourier Series here. But what are the $c_i$ here?

2) What do I have to do to show uniformly convergence here?

Answer (score 4):

We have the uniform convergence since
$$\frac{|\cos((2n-1)x)|}{(2n-1)^2}\leq\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$$
and the series $\displaystyle \sum_n \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$ is convergent.

Comment: And what are the $c_i$ here?

Comment: This shiws the absolute convergence - not the uniform convergence, or?

Comment: @math12 The [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) gives uniform convergence.