# Show that Fourier series of $f(x)=|x|$ converges pointwise and uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The Fourier series of $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ can be written as $$f(x)\sim \dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}.$$

This post [Show absolute and uniform convergence of a Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570694/show-absolute-and-uniform-convergence-of-a-fourier-series) has shown that this Fourier series converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$. However, I want to show that this Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$ on the whole $[-\pi,\pi]$.

To this end, I define the partial sum $$S_{N}:=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx},$$ and then try to estimate $|f(x)-S_{N}(x)|$. I have some preliminary result, but it does not give me $$\sup_{x\in[-\pi,\pi]}|f(x)-S_{N}(x)|\longrightarrow 0,$$ when $N\rightarrow\infty$.  Certainly, I can use the $\epsilon-N$ definition, but my estimate outcome is not that computation friendly either for me to get $N$ for each $\epsilon$.

---

The following is my estimate:

As $|e^{-inx}|=1$, we can have the following estimate
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-S_{N}(f)(x)|=\Bigg|f(x)-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}\Bigg|&\leq |f(x)|+\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\Bigg|\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}\Bigg|\\
&=|x|+\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\Bigg|\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}\Bigg|\\
&\leq \dfrac{3\pi}{2}+\dfrac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\\
&\leq \dfrac{3\pi}{2}+\dfrac{4}{\pi}\Bigg(\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{6}-\dfrac{1}{N+1}\Bigg)\\
&=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}-\dfrac{4}{\pi(N+1)}.
\end{align*}

---

Then I got stuck. We have a good outcome that the bound does not depend on $x$, but solve the bound $<\epsilon$ seems really complicated. Is there any way for me to make this nicer? The best case would be that I can directly conclude the bound goes to $0$ when $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Thank you!

---

**Edit: Pointwise Convergence**

As the answer of "Mostafa Ayaz" suggested, we need to firstly prove that the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$ pointwise on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

In fact, the reason why I directly proved the uniform convergence was that I did not know how to prove the pointwise convergence.

I mean, it is straightforward to prove that the series convergences, but how to prove it convergent pointwise to $f(x)$ on the whole $[-\pi,\pi]$?

**Edit 2:**

Okay. I just recalled that $f(x)=|x|$ is Holder continuous, so the partial sum must converge pointwise.

Comment: Also worth looking at Dini's criterion.

Comment: @copper.hat yes. Dini's condition, a corollary from Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, shows that if $0<\alpha<1$, then it actually converges uniformly. But if $\alpha=1$, the partial sum converges pointwise, we cannot extend it. So we then use the accepted answer to prove the uniform convergence manually. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but using the triangle inequality at the first step is a bit overkill and leads to irrelevant bounds. Just do the following
$$
|f(x)-S_{N}(f)(x)|{=\Bigg|f(x)-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}\Bigg|
\\=
\Bigg|\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}-\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}\Bigg|
\\=
\Bigg|2\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}\Bigg|
\\\le
\Bigg|2\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}\Bigg|
\\\le
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{4}{\pi n^{2}}
}
$$
From now, it is very straightforward.

Comment: I don't quite follow your second line. How did you get the infinite sum? and why do we have $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $f(x)$? Thank you!

Comment: This is the line $f(x)\sim \dfrac{\pi}{2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}-1}{\pi n^{2}}e^{-inx}$ where I substituted $\sim$ with $=$ and we are allowed to do that since the summation is convergent anywhere on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: oh okay. I get it. but we need to prove the pointwise convergence at the first place. But that's easy as $|x|$ is holder continuous (even Lipschitz). Thank you!